# Can't get the BackColor of labels on a subform to reflect the new color--- even after I first changed BackStyle to "1" and repainted the form

Tags: vba, ms-access, label, subform, backcolor

I am stumped as to why the BackColor for labels on an MS Access subform will not update visually.  I wrote some code to change the BackStyle to "1" first, then changed the color of BackColor.  I ran tests and found that the BackStyle and BackColor have actually been updated in the system, but not in the Property Sheet--- which still shows BackStyle as "0" and BackColor as the default color.  The color of the label on the subform also retains the default color.  I also get no error messages, but that doesn't mean I'm not royally messing something up. I even tried to repaint the form to see if that would do the trick, but to no avail. Here is the simple code below:

```
Dim frm As Form
Dim ctl As Control


Set frm = Me![subfrm_Review Forecast Totals].Form

For Each ctl In frm.Controls

    If ctl.ControlType = acLabel And ctl.Name = "2020-12-25_Label" Then    
       
        ctl.BackStyle = 1
        ctl.BackColor = vbGreen      
                    
    End If

Next ctl

Me.Repaint
```

End Sub

Comment: The property sheet holds values at design time but you're updating the properties at runtime, it's correct that the property sheet lists the default value. Am i missing something?

Comment: If you add this on the line before `End Sub`, and run the procedure again, what does it show you? `MsgBox Me![subfrm_Review Forecast Totals]![2020-12-25_Label].BackStyle`

Comment: Instead of Label controls, can use textbox (Locked Yes and TabStop No) to act like label then use Conditional Formatting - no VBA.

Comment: @Hansup... when I enter that code before End Sub, it's gives the answer "1"

Comment: @June7... I was just using this code to see if I could actually effect the backColor. The finished code will be a much more complex "if" statement. Thus regular condition formatting wouldn't be able to do it.

Comment: Code does dynamically affect backcolor during runtime. However, saving this runtime property setting requires saving form design. Why do you feel the dynamic runtime setting needs to be permanently saved?